# How to get bulk documents offline from a sharepoint intranet?

Tags: offline

I am using sharepoint 2010 as a intranet. In this intranet are many important documents for the company. I have also collegeas which are working on boats somewhere in the middle of the sea. They dont have access to this sharepoint intranet because they are not on our network.

I am looking for some solution where it is possible for these collegeas outside the network to access some documents offline. For example: Before they go to the boat/sea they can download for example documents from a whole library or site inclusive some folder structure. I know it is possible to download just 1 document, but thats to much work for many documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2010, you should go for SharePoint WorkSpace. It is a desktop tool that allows you to offline sync material from SharePoint 2010 sites: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/synchronize-sharepoint-content-with-sharepoint-workspace-HA101854201.aspx

Previously, it was possible to us OneDrive (SkyDrive) for Business to sync 2010 content as well, but this was never officially supported by Microsoft and has been disabled in later updates of OneDrive for Business. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2904784/en